# Create a condition in html within javascript

Tags: javascript

I have my `javascript` this way, that I create a pivot table:

```
var util = $('#utl4').val();
var linha = ``; 
$.getJSON('./atman', function (data) {

  var arrayLength = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
   Id = data[i][0];
   DataRegisto  = data[i][1];
   Destino = data[i][2];
   Assunto = data[i][3];
   Descricao = data[i][4];
   nome = data[i][5];
   colaborador = data[i][6];

   linha += `<tr id=${ Id }>             
   <td>${ Id }</td> 
   <td>${ DataRegisto }</td> 
   <td>${ Destino }</td> 
   <td>${ Assunto }</td>
   <td>${ Descricao }</td> 
   <td>${ nome }</td>
   <td><?php if($colaborador == $util): ?><button type="button" data-target="#ad_man" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_man" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><?php endif; ?></td>
   <td><?php if($colaborador == $util): ?><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rman"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"><?php endif; ?></td>
   </tr>`; 
}
```

In these two lines:

```
<td><?php if($colaborador == $util): ?><button type="button" data-target="#ad_man" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_man" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><?php endif; ?></td>
<td><?php if($colaborador == $util): ?><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rman"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"><?php endif; ?></td>
```

I intend to create the condition I have on those lines, but that way it doesn't work.

Can anyone help solve the problem?

Comment: Where do you set the variables `$colabrador` and `$util`?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, then JS runs on the browser. You can't "mix and match" like that.

Comment: Wait... those are both **JS** variables... So just... use JS... ``<td>${colaborador == util ? `<button ...>` : ''}</td>``

Comment: @Barmar It is inside the javascript. `var util = $('#utl4').val();` is the first line of javascript in the question. And `colaborador = data[i][6];` is inside the for in javascript

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Thanks, solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest expressions inside template literals.

**Note:** You cannot execute PHP tags in the client, also your variable `colaborador` should not be prefixed like a PHP variable.

```js
const data = getData();
const arrayLength = data.length;
const tbody = document.querySelector('.info-table tbody');
const util = document.querySelector('#utl4').value;

for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  let id          = data[i][0];
  let dataRegisto = data[i][1];
  let destino     = data[i][2];
  let assunto     = data[i][3];
  let descricao   = data[i][4];
  let nome        = data[i][5];
  let colaborador = data[i][6];

  let linha = `
    <tr id=${ id }>             
      <td>${ id }</td> 
      <td>${ dataRegisto }</td> 
      <td>${ destino }</td> 
      <td>${ assunto }</td>
      <td>${ descricao }</td> 
      <td>${ nome }</td>
      <td>
        ${
          colaborador == util
            ? `<button
                  type="button" data-target="#ad_man"
                  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_man">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
              </button>` : ''
        }
        ${
          colaborador == util
            ? `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rman">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
              </button>` : ''
        }
      </td>
    </tr>
  `;
   
   tbody.innerHTML += linha;
}

function getData() {
  return [
    [ 1 , '2020-07-15' , 'Here'       , 'Stuff'   , '' , 'Joe'  , 'yes' ],
    [ 2 , '2020-07-15' , 'There'      , 'Things'  , '' , 'Jane' , 'no'  ],
    [ 3 , '2020-07-15' , 'Everywhere' , 'Nothing' , '' , 'Bob'  , 'yes' ]
  ];
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table info-table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Data Registo</th>
        <th>Destino</th>
        <th>Assunto</th>
        <th>Descricao</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Colaborador</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Colaborador</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="utl4" value="yes">
  </div>
</div>
```